# Xamarin TimeSpan use with times smaller than 1 millisecond

Tags: c#, xamarin, timespan

I have a Class library (.net Standard 2.0) that uses TimeSpan. If I use the class library in a console application everything works as expected. However when I use it in a Xamarin Forms (Shell App) application, TimeSpan is 00:00:00 for any value smaller than 1 millisecond. My calculations unfortunately require microseconds.

As an example the code below (The actual code is more complex than this, this is just the easiest to show the "error"):

`var timetest = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.02286 / 943.356);`

results in the following for the console application
[image]
and this for the Xamarin application
[image]

I see that for the console application the values for Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds and Milliseconds are 32-bit values but for the Xamarin one it is 16-bit.

Is there a way for me to handle the TimeSpan value in Xamarin the same as in the Console Application? Or is it not possible and I have to modify the Class library to just use a Double to represent the seconds?

Comment: `TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(100);` - this creates a TimeSpan with 100 ticks, or .01 ms.  Tested on iOS with no problems

Comment: @Jason, Thanks this works. I changed my code to `var timetest = new TimeSpan((int)(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond*0.02286 / 943.356));` and I get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, Jason for giving the answer in the comments. I'm going to put it here so everyone can clearly see it

Here you create 100 ticks so the equivalent of 0.1 ms:

```
TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(100);
```

So, in this exact context it's:

```
var timetest = new TimeSpan((int)(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond*0.02286 / 943.356));
```

For more about TimeSpan: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_TimeSpan__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_